# Ending scrapy runspider before full execution is done

Tags: python, scrapy

```
class PythonEventsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'goodspider'
    start_urls=['https://www.amazon.com/s?me=A33IZBYF4IBZTP&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER']
    details=[]

    def parse(self, response):
        base_url="https://www.amazon.com"
        #code here
        next_page=base_url+response.xpath('//li[@class="a-last"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        print(next_page)
        if "page=3" not in next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page,callback=self.parse)
        else:
            #raise CloseSpider('bandwidth_exceeded')
            #exit("Done")
```

Hello,i would like to stop the program when it reaches page 3 the url will be as follows `https://www.amazon.com/s?i=merchant-items&me=A33IZBYF4IBZTP&page=3&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&qid=1555628764&ref=sr_pg_3` I Have tried some of the answers online but it didn't work the program kept run. what i want is to add a line or a function in the `else`statement to end  `scrapy runspider test.py -o test.csv`

Comment: The documentation points at raising `CloseSpider`. What is the exact behaviour you see when you comment your `raise CloseSpider` line back in? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27001586/scrapy-not-responding-to-closespider-exception and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44566184/scrapy-spider-not-terminating-with-use-of-closespider-extension

Answer (score 0):

`CloseSpider` will process all the pending requests too

So you must have to set `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=1`

Comment: this will not work because I have `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=10`

Comment: @hadesfv then there is no way to do it, because scrapy is asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

If you really want your script to completely stop at that point, you can terminate your script as you would do for any other Python script: [use `sys.exit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73673/939364).

However, this means that item processing and other parts of the internal workins of Scrapy won’t have a chance to run. If this is a problem for you, there is no other way beyond Umair’s response.